# Why all LGBT+ communities forbidden?

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, homosexuality, sexuality

I am aware that it is haram to act homosexual, as Prophet Lut (AS) told his people not to have sex between men and men. But what I don't understand is why all the other gender identities are forbidden. I found that doing Lesbian acts is haram from a post by Rebecca J. Stones, but there are too many identities to be explicitly stated to be forbidden. So is there a universal verse or hadith that makes all these identities haram? I know that in verses 49-50 of Surah Al-Shura, Allah says that humans have been created male and female, and the opposite sexes marry. But that technically doesn't disqualify acting any other gender identities from being haram.

Comment: Look at https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/81212/55518 what I get from it, however Allah has created you and however you received or changed that, it is not a question on what you feel but what you are doing.

Comment: So, what I have gathered from my reading here, it is *not* forbidden to *be* homosexual, lesbian or whatever you can think of, and the only but solid requirement is that you don't give in to those desires and *do not act haram*. For some this is easy, for some this is hard to follow. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No, that's what I got from my research as well. I will edit my question to be more clear.

Comment: See https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5886

Comment: @UmH But this doesn’t apply to asexuals for example.